# How to exit a process run with C++ if it takes more than 5 seconds?

Tags: c++, process, execution-time

I'm implementing a checking system in C++. It runs executables with different tests. If the solution is not correct, it can take forever for it to finish with certain hard tests. That's why I want to limit the execution time to 5 seconds.

I'm using system() function to run executables:

```
system("./solution");
```

.NET has a great `WaitForExit()` method, what about native C++?. I'm also using Qt, so Qt-based solutions are welcome.

So is there a way to limit external process' execution time to 5 seconds?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `QProcess` with a `QTimer` so you can kill it after 5 seconds. Something like;

```
QProcess proc;
QTimer timer;

connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(checkProcess());
proc.start("/full/path/to/solution");
timer.start(5*1000);
```

and implement `checkProcess()`;

```
void checkProcess()
{
    if (proc.state() != QProcess::NotRunning())
        proc.kill();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a separate thread for doing your required work and then from another thread, issue the 
`pthread_cancle ()` call after some time (5 sec) to the worker thread. Make sure to register proper handler and thread's cancelability options.

For more details refer to: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread.html) to allow you to make the system call in a separate thread and use the `timed_join` method to restrict the running time.

Something like:

```
void run_tests()
{
    system("./solution");
}

int main()
{
    boost::thread test_thread(&run_tests);

    if (test_thread.timed_join(boost::posix_time::seconds(5)))
    {
        // Thread finished within 5 seconds, all fine.
    }
    else
    {
        // Wasn't complete within 5 seconds, need to stop the thread
    }
}
```

The hardest part is to determine how to nicely terminate the thread (note that test_thread is still running).

Comment: timed_join is deprecated and will be gone in boost 1.56, better use "test_thread.try_join_for(boost::chrono::seconds(5))"

Answer (score 1):

```
void WaitForExit(void*)
{
    Sleep(5000);
    exit(0);
}
```

And then use it (Windows specific):

```
_beginthread(WaitForExit, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm on Mac OS X, and I want it to be platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

Solution testing system on Windows should use [Job objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28VS.85%29.aspx) to restrict it's access to the system and execution time (not the real time, BTW).

Comment: I'm on Mac OS :) And I want to make it cross platform.

Comment: Anyway, terminating process based on real time measurements is wrong: if some background process awakes and starts to use substantial amount of CPU time while your "solution" is running, you'll terminate it earlier than needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Posix compliant systems (of which MacOS and Unix generally are), use `fork` `execv` and ``waitpid`instead of`system`.An example can be found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Creation-Example.html#Process-Creation-Example). The only really tricky bit now is how to get a waitpid with a timeout. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282176/waitpid-equivalent-with-timeout) for ideas.