# Why waiting indefinitely - timerfd_create? Where have i gone wrong?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I have created a timer which can expire, in 5 seconds using `timerfd_create`, but i can see that it is waiting indefinitely.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
enter code here
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  struct itimerspec its;
  struct epoll_event event, revent;

  int timer_fd, efd;

  /* Setting timer interval */
  its.it_interval.tv_sec=1;
  its.it_interval.tv_nsec=0;

  /* Setting timer expiration */
  its.it_value.tv_sec=5;
  its.it_value.tv_nsec=0;

  efd=epoll_create(2);
  event.data.fd=timer_fd;

  event.events=EPOLLIN;
  epoll_ctl(efd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, timer_fd, &event);

  timer_fd=timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);

  if(timer_fd==-1)
  {
    perror("timerfd:");
  }

  if(timerfd_settime(timer_fd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &its, NULL)==-1)
  {
   perror("timerfd_settime error:");
  }

  printf("Starting the timer...");

  while(1) {
     epoll_wait(efd, &revent, 1, -1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the order of calls to `epoll_ctl` and `timerfd_create`. Right now you are adding some random integer value to the event set.

#### Edit 0:

Several points:

- [`timerfd_create(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) produces a file descriptor, just like [`open(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/open.2.html) or [`socket(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html). You have to assign the return value to the `timer_fd` variable *before* giving it to the [`epoll_ctl(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html), otherwise it's just a random integer value from the stack.
- Don't use `TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME` - you are asking the kernel to start a timer that expires one second after the [Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) (which is not that big of a deal - it'll just expire immediately).
- When the timer expires [`epoll_wait(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) returns the number of ready file descriptors, `1` in your example, and you are expected to handle that. You, on the other hand, just ignore that return value and spin around in a tight loop, so you don't even know the timer is expiring.
- You need to read from timer file descriptor to consume the expiration event. Otherwise all subsequent calls to `epoll_wait(2)` will just return immediately since the descriptor remains in the "signaled" state.
- Always check the return values of the system calls and handle error conditions based on the value of [`errno(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/errno.3.html) - manual page for each call gives you possible error values.

#### Edit 1:

You do want a loop around the `epoll_wait(2)` (or `select(2)`. or `poll(2)`), but you need:

1. handle the IO events being signaled (that's the whole point of these multiplexing APIs - being able to wait on multiple descriptors and dispatch the events), and
2. be able to break out of that loop (on a signal, on input from a dedicated file descriptor ala [self-pipe trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282176/waitpid-equivalent-with-timeout), or on some application event).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean first timerfd_create and then epoll_ctl? If that is what you mean, then sorry it still does not work.

Comment: I have got the solution, but tell me isn't there any other way to wait for the file descriptor rather than waiting in a tight while loop?

Comment: @Nikolai, great answer. I'd only add that, instead of using a pipe to signal the end of the loop, I'd use an eventfd[0], which is just cheaper than the pipe that holds two FDs and the pipe data structure:

[0] http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html