# Using fork() to output 1 array element per child, C++

Tags: c++, fork

I have an assignment that is to take in a string from the command line, reverse it and output each character in a separate child process using fork().  I'm just not getting the correct output from the fork() calls.  The problem is that indexes get jumbled up on output, like 3, 1, 2, 0 when it should just be 3,2,1,0 ... etc...  What makes it more confusing is it randomly is successful when the word is 3 characters long (but not always), but routinely is incorrect for words with 4+ characters.  The loop works correctly without the fork() call.

Here is my main function, and the problem exists within the for loop.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    pid_t childpid = 0;
    int i;
    char* invert = new char[strlen(argv[1])+1];
    int invert_length = strlen(argv[1]);
    strcpy(invert, argv[1]);
    for(i=invert_length-1; i>=0; i--){
        childpid = fork();
        if(childpid==(pid_t) 0){
            //I am the child            
            cout<<"Child ["<< i <<"] = "  << invert[i] <<"."<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple modification of your program makes it work. Let the child do the next fork. Each process waits for the one it spawned.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    pid_t childpid = 0;
    int i;
    char* invert = new char[strlen(argv[1])+1];
    int invert_length = strlen(argv[1]);
    strcpy(invert, argv[1]);
    for(i=invert_length-1; i>=0; i--){
        childpid = fork();
        if(childpid==(pid_t) 0){
            //I am the child
            cout<<"Child ["<< i <<"] = "  << invert[i] <<"."<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    wait(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:** Skizz objected that each process executed its work before launching the next one. There was no requirement in the question that all the processes be launched first, but the version below does that.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    pid_t childpid = 0;
    int i;
    char* invert = new char[strlen(argv[1])+1];
    int invert_length = strlen(argv[1]);
    strcpy(invert, argv[1]);
    for(i=0; i<invert_length; ++i){
        childpid = fork();
        if(childpid!=(pid_t) 0){
            wait(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i-->0) cout<<"Child ["<< i <<"] = "  << invert[i] <<"." <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  I was just about to log off after using a sleep(5/(i+1)) method that timed out each one effectively, but saw your post and think this is much better.

Comment: Although this does indeed solve the original problem, it's effectively a single process solution. Each new process is created when the previous process completes. If I were a teacher setting this problem, I'd probably fail this answer as the central concept is coordinating concurrent processes rather than how to serialise them. Serialising them defeats the whole point of using multiple processes.

Comment: @Skizz: Any form of coordination effectively serializes them. The solution I proposed is the most efficient way to do so, given the parameters of the problem. Regards

Comment: @Skizz: I added another solution to the answer that launches all the processes first. Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is the same situation, as with pthreads. No warranty, that childs will be executed in spawn order. Mind SIGCHLD.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the fork call spawns a new process, duplicating the calling process. As you do this inside a loop, you now have lots of processes all wanting to be executed at the same time. The order they get to be execute (since the CPU can only execute one process at a time*) is dependent on the OS as that is the thing that chooses which process to execute, so the output becomes indeterminate.

To fix the problem, each spawned process needs to know when to output which means using some sort of sychronisation between processes.

Notes:

- I've ignored hyperthreading / multiple cores for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You could fork, then call `wait`, thus satisfying the HW requirements.
My original answer below is how you could run this in a more complex environment (a real app) and how you would be able to take advantage from running some code in a separate process

addition of `wait` as noted above

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    pid_t childpid = 0;
    int i;
    char* invert = new char[strlen(argv[1])+1];
    int invert_length = strlen(argv[1]);
    strcpy(invert, argv[1]);
    for(i=invert_length-1; i>=0; i--){
        childpid = fork();
        if(childpid==(pid_t) 0){
            //I am the child            
            cout<<"Child ["<< i <<"] = "  << invert[i] <<"."<<endl;
            break;
        }
        else {
          int stat;
              wait(&stat);
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

---

I agree with @illusionoflife, but if its homework then it must be possible

You can setup an eventhandler (for example with libevent) for SIGCHLD, then launch the next child after the first SIGGCHLD is received etc

The point of this excercise may not be a load-balancing across multiple CPUs but to show the things you can do with [Copy On Write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434218/libevent-signal-handling-sigchld-specifically) is a question I asked a few months back, to get you started