# How can I get the PID of a dead child process and use it in the parent?

Tags: c, unix, fork, freebsd, sigchld

I'm trying to make a C program (for FreeBSD, Unix) which creates 4 children processes in a loop. Each child does things and, when they die, they are replaced immediately by other children. So, in the end, I have 4 children working all the time.

Each child PID has to be registered in a table and, after they're dead, the PID of the table has to be deleted. This is the part in which I'm having troubles.

So in the first try I have tried to create a handler which sends to a global variable the PID of the dead child:

```
int global_variable;

void handler_SIGCHLD(int sig)
{
    pid_t son;
    int e;

    do {
        son = wait3(&e, WNOHANG, NULL);
        if ((son > (pid_t)0) && (WIFEXITED(e) || WIFSIGNALED(e)))
        {
            global_variable = son;
        }
    } while (son > (pid_t)0);
}
```

Then I use it in the parent to delete the PID of the dead child from the table. But then I realise that, if two children die at the same time, one of the PIDs will be overwritten by the other.

How can I avoid this situation?

Comment: Wait for the children without WNOHANG outside of any handler. Do nothing in the SIGHCLD handler. Alternatively, if you must do it in the handler, don't use a single global variable, use an array of dead PIDs so that they don't overwrite each other.

Comment: Another alternative. In the handler, set a single `sig_atomic_t` flag and return. Outside of the handler, if the flag is set, then *hold SIGCHLD*, do the `while (son = wait3(&e, WNOHANG, NULL)) {...}` thing, and re-enable SIGCHLD.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be doing this from a signal handler. You should not be doing anything from a signal handler (if you desire to remain sane).

A reliable approach is to translate the `SIGCHLD` signals into file descriptor events which you integrate into an event loop (`select`, `poll`, `epoll`...). When you observe an event, you use `waitpid(..., WNOHANG)` in a loop to collect all the dead children. See more on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398491/1020667

The above answer assumes that you're on Linux and use `signalfd` (a Linux specific facility) to translate signals into file descriptors. But alternatively you can use the "self-pipe" trick (with great care), or `kqueue` (FreeBSD, OSX). Note that with `kqueue`, there isn't an intermediate file descriptor, you directly receive signal events just like file descriptor events.

On the other hand, you can get around all these low-level details by using a portable event loop library. Some libraries already provide facilities for starting and watching child processes. I recommend `libuv` (of node.js).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I'm using FreeBSD (Unix).

Comment: @Vertice Then you can use kqueue, see updated answer.