# process synchronization between a parent and multiple child processes using signals

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I am learning how to use signals in linux. There are 4 child processes and one parent process. My output is supposed to go in these stages:

Parent receives signal from child 1

Parent receives signal from child 2

Parent receives signal from child 3

Parent receives signal from child 4

Init ended

Phase 1 begins

Child 1 receives signal from parent

Child 2 receives signal from parent

Child 3 receives signal from parent

Child 4 receives signal from parent

Parent receives signal from child 1

Parent receives signal from child 2

Parent receives signal from child 3

Parent receives signal from child 4

Phase 1 ends

Phase 2 begins

Child 1 receives signal from parent

Child 2 receives signal from parent

Child 3 receives signal from parent

Child 4 receives signal from parent

I am currently trying to do the part before Phase 1 ends and I am struggling. Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXCP 3
int ccount=0;
void p_action(int sig){
   if (sig == SIGUSR2){
      printf("\ncontroller(%d): Received signal SIGUSR2 from child   process\n", 
            (int)getpid());
    }
    --ccount;
 }

 void c_action(int sig){
    if (sig == SIGUSR1){
      printf("\ncompute(%d): Received signal SIGUSR1 from parent process %d\n", 
            (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    }
    exit(0);
 }

int main(){

pid_t pid[MAXCP], parent_pid;
//int nprocs = 0;
ccount = MAXCP;

static struct sigaction pact, cact[MAXCP];

pact.sa_handler = p_action;
sigaction(SIGUSR2, &pact, NULL);


int count;
for (count = 0; count < MAXCP; count++){
    switch(pid[count] = fork()){
        case -1:
            perror("Fork error");
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            //sleep(1);
            cact[count].sa_handler = c_action;
            sigaction(SIGUSR1, &cact[count], NULL);
            printf("Sending SIGUSR2 to parent");
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
            pause();
            break;
        default:
            pause();
            //printf("Parent is sleeping");

            while (ccount != MAXCP){
                sleep(60);
            }
            for (ccount = 0; ccount < MAXCP; ccount++)
                kill(pid[count], SIGUSR1);
            break;

    }   
}


return 0;
}
```

My output is such:

```
// When I use the above code
controller(3132): Received signal SIGUSR2 from child process
// When I comment out the pause in the child section
controller(3140): Received signal SIGUSR2 from child process
Sending SIGUSR2 to parent
controller(3141): Received signal SIGUSR2 from child process
Sending SIGUSR2 to parentSending SIGUSR2 to parentSending SIGUSR2 to     parentSending SIGUSR2 to parentSending SIGUSR2 to parent
controller(3142): Received signal SIGUSR2 from child process
^C
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `--ccount;` is undefined, you can only use `volatile sig_atomic_t` objects in signal handlers. In worst case your signal handler modifies the bytes in the middle of `ccount != MAXCP` or any other use of it, or something equally evil.

Comment: I  put in the volatile sig_atomic_t and II still go the same result.

Comment: Didn't mean that as a solution, just pointing it out that it was undefined behaviour and might contribute to overall weirdness now or later.

Comment: so what can i do to synchronise?

Comment: afaik you can not synchronize signals: sequentially sending and receiving signal in child and parent does not seem appropriate. you can not make sure even the sequence of execution of child and parent

Comment: Is there a way for the parent to receive a set amout of signals before responding?

Comment: There's also one thing you have to take in to account: [signals can be coalesced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398298/handling-sigchld), if they're sent faster than you can handle. That means you receive 1 signal for many. It'll break your counting. Also, `printf` is not signal safe. Don't use it in a handler.

Comment: I'm really out of my league in this matter anyway, but look in to realtime signals. I think in Linux they should queue instead of coalesce if blocked and they guarantee delivery order to match sending order etc.

Comment: SO if i really wanted to get the output as above, how would I go about it? Thanks again for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use signals for, is not 100% match with what they are designed for. The most significant problem is that signals acts as an hardware interrupt controller. If multiple signals of the same value happens "at the same time", they will appear to be merged into just one signal in the receiver. In the example below, we work around this by using sleep with different value in each child.

So when the kernel is the reschedule the process, it just checks if each signal has been received since last time process was active, and forwards them into the process if needed. It does not know how many times it happened.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXCP 3
volatile int ccount=0;
void p_action(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr){
   if (sig == SIGUSR2){
      printf("\ncontroller(%d): Received signal SIGUSR2 from child %d process\n",
            (int)getpid(), (int)info->si_pid);
    }
    --ccount;
 }

 void c_action(int sig){
    if (sig == SIGUSR1){
      printf("\ncompute(%d): Received signal SIGUSR1 from parent process %d\n",
            (int)getpid(), (int)getppid());
    }
 }

int main(){
    int count;
    pid_t pid[MAXCP];
    ccount = MAXCP;

    struct sigaction pact;

    pact.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART; /* if signal comes on top of each other, we need this */
    pact.sa_sigaction = p_action;
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &pact, NULL);

    /* spawdn children */
    for (count = 0; count < MAXCP; count++){
        switch(pid[count] = fork()){
            case -1:
                perror("Fork error");
                exit(1);
            case 0:
                {
                    struct sigaction cact;
                    cact.sa_flags = 0;
                    cact.sa_handler = c_action;
                    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &cact, NULL);
                    pause();
                    sleep(1);
                    printf("Sending SIGUSR2 to parent (%d)\n", getppid());
                    sleep(count+1);
                    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
                    exit(0);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    sleep (1); /* let children have time to configure sigaction() */

    /* notify all children */
    for (count = 0; count < MAXCP; count++){
        printf ("Sending SIGUSR1 to child %d\n", (int)pid[count]);
        kill(pid[count], SIGUSR1);
    }

    /* wait for children to notify back */
    while (ccount)
    {
         usleep(10000); /* else CPU throttles */
    }

    for (count = 0; count < MAXCP; count++){
        int status;
        waitpid (pid[count], &status, 0);
        printf ("Child process %d reaped. status=%d\n", pid[count], status);
        kill(pid[count], SIGUSR1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Image the kernel has a record per process about which signals it has received while sleeping.

```
struct Process
{
   bool hasReceivedSIGINT;
   bool hasReceivedSIGUSR1;
   bool hasReceivedSIGUSR2;
   bool hasReceivedSIGUSR3;
};
```

A signal is used to "nudge" other processes. A good example is to make a process reload configuration file. For IPC communication, pipe() is a better approach.

Comment: Stian:Thanks. You have helped me a lot in the thinking of this problem.