# Will a parent process always receive SIGCHLD when a child process dies?

Tags: c++, c, select, signals, zombie-process

I am using the `signalfd()` function in non-blocking mode and the *close on `exec()`* feature also turned on:

```
sigset_t set;
sigemptyset(&set);
sigaddset(&set, SIGCHLD);

f_socket = signalfd(-1, &set, SFD_NONBLOCK | SFD_CLOEXEC);
```

Then I listen for signals using the `poll()` command.

Is it at all possible, when using that mechanism, to miss a `SIGCHLD` signal?

I have a server that has been running for nearly 3 weeks and it has one zombie. The only way I can think of for such to happen is that a child process died and somehow the parent did not receive the signal. Each time I access the server, it generally creates many children (the minimum is around 10 and I think the maximum is around 30) all of which get caught. So I am not too sure why just one would somehow *disappear*.

Comment: You may have an issue with multiple children exiting virtually simultaneously.  Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398298/handling-sigchld

Comment: @TonyB: You are correct. This most likely is the same issue. I just added a comment to one of the answer to the question you linked which points to the relevant part of the Linux documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398298/handling-sigchld#comment63516377_8398491

Comment: @TonyB, you are absolutely correct. This is a duplicate of that other question. The person mentions the exact same problem/concern.

Comment: @alk, I actually added your links in that answer. Easier to find! Also feel free to mark my question as a duplicate.