# What will happen if a signal is triggered in its same trap handler?

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I have the following bash

```
chld_handler() {
    trap '' CHLD # ignore while we handle
    echo "$(date)" # this won't trigger chld now
    trap 'chld_handler' CHLD # restore
}

# I want to be notified of the exit of any of these processes
xterm &
xterm &
xterm &

trap 'chld_handler' CHLD # first time setup
```

What would happen if one of the job processes exits, the `chld_handler` is invoked and while the handler runs another of the job processes exits? Will the second `CHLD` signal be queued?

Comment: Somewhat related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398298/handling-multiple-sigchld/8398491