# Why can't I catch SIGCHLD every time after fork?

Tags: c, signals, fork, signal-handling, sigaction

I am trying to create 4 child processes and until the children die, parent should wait. I wrote a program but when I run this code, 1 out of 10, it can't catch the SIGCHLD from every child and my program goes to infinite loop after. It happens really rare but still..

Could you tell me why and how can I fix it?

Here is my code.

```
sig_atomic_t child_exit_status;
sig_atomic_t child_numbers = 0;

void clean_up(int signal_number, siginfo_t * info, void* context)
{
    //printf("SIGCHILD from %d calling\n", info->si_pid);
    waitpid(info->si_pid, &child_exit_status, 0);
    child_numbers++;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // SIGCHLD catcher 
    struct sigaction sigchld_action;
    memset(&sigchld_action, 0, sizeof(sigchld_action));
    sigchld_action.sa_sigaction = &clean_up;
    sigchld_action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sigchld_action, NULL);


    int pid1, pid2, pid3, pid4;


    printf("pid : %d\n", getpid());

    pid1 = fork();
    //child1
    if(pid1 == 0)
    {
        printf("child1 %d, parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    }
    else
    {
        pid2 = fork();
        //child2
        if(pid2 == 0)
        {
            printf("child2 %d, parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        }
        else
        {
            pid3 = fork();
            //child3
            if(pid3 == 0)
            {
                printf("child3 %d, parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            }
            else
            {
                pid4 = fork();
                //child4
                if(pid4 == 0)
                {
                    printf("child4 %d, parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
                }
                else
                {
                    while(child_numbers < 4)
                    {

                    }
                    printf("i got the signals.");
                }

            }

        }

    }



    return 0;
}
```

I tried something new but it also doesn't work..

```
void clean_up(int signal_number, siginfo_t * info, void* context)
{
    printf("SIGCHILD from %d calling\n", info->si_pid);
    while (1)
    {
        int status;
        pid_t pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
        if (pid <= 0) 
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            break;
        }
    }
    child_numbers++;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling multiple SIGCHLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398298/handling-multiple-sigchld)

Comment: I have no idea about signalfd..

Comment: I m sorry but I couldnt understand how to use WNOHANG. I ve read more about and I edited my question, could you please check?

Comment: I checked the link you sent and I tried to initialize to my code. I put what I coded in my question. The problem is, still I cant catch all the SIGCHILD..

Comment: You don't catch all SIGCHILD because the signals are merged into one. `child_numbers++` should be counted in `else`

Comment: this time, it never becomes 4..

Comment: Why do you break the loop in the else?