# Is there a version of the wait() system call that sets a timeout?

Tags: c, linux, multiprocessing, wait

Is there any way to use the `wait()` system call with a timeout, besides using a busy-waiting or busy-sleeping loop?

I've got a parent process that `fork`s itself and `exec`s a child executable. It then waits for the child to finish, grabs its output by whatever means appropriate, and and performs further processing. If the process does not finish within a certain period of time, it assumes that its execution timed out, and does something else. Unfortunately, this timeout detection is necessary given the nature of the problem.

Comment: Mind if we ask why you need such a thing? (in case there are alternatives)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waitpid equivalent with timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282176/waitpid-equivalent-with-timeout)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not a wait call that takes a timeout.

What you can do instead is install a signal handler that sets a flag for SIGCHLD, and use select() to implement a timeout. select() will be interrupted by a signal.

```
static volatile int punt;
static void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    punt = 1;
}

...

struct timeval timeout = {10,0};
int rc;

signal(SIGCHLD, sig_handler);

fork/exec stuff
//select will get interrupted by a signal

rc = select(0, NULL,NULL,NULL, &timeout ); 
if (rc == 0) {
// timed out
} else if (punt) {
    //child terminated
}
```

More logic is needed if you have other signal you need to handle as well though

Comment: If you're already installing a polling loop, you might as well set up a signalfd to catch the signal.

Comment: In the example, is `&tv` actually supposed to be `&timeout`? If not, how is `timeout` supposed to be used?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `waitpid` together with the `WNOHANG` option and a sleep.

```
while(waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG) == 0) {
    sleep(1);
}
```

But this will be an active sleeping. However I see no other way using the `wait` type of functions.

Comment: "besides using a busy-waiting or busy-sleeping loop" I consider this an inelegant last resort.

Comment: @Alex Seems that I've not read the question carefully enough. But however I don't see a way beside this

Answer (score 4):

On linux, you can also solve this problem using `signalfd`. `signalfd` essentially takes a set of signals and creates an fd which you can read; each block you read corresponds to a signal which has fired. (You should block these signals with sigprocmask so that they are not actually sent.)

The advantage of `signalfd` is that you can use the fd with `select`, `poll`, or `epoll`, all of which allow for timeouts, and all of which allow you to wait for other things as well.

One note: If the same signal fires twice before the corresponding `struct signalfd_siginfo` is read, you'll only receive a single indication. So when you get a `SIGCHLD` indication, you need to `waitpid(-1, &status, &WNOHANG)` repeatedly until it returns -1.

On FreeBSD, you can achieve the same effect rather more directly using `kqueue` and a `kevent` of type `EVFILT_PROC`. (You can also kqueue a SIGCHLD event, but EVFILT_PROC lets you specify the events by child pid instead of globally for all children.) This should also work on Mac OS X, but I've never tried it.