# How would I set a timeout in this simple C shell?

Tags: c, time, process

The code as it is right now forks a command, and executes it the specified number of times. I am new to C and don't know much about syntax. Basically, I want to somehow be able to set a maximum duration for the different processes I am making, and have the process be terminated when it reaches that duration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

// tokenize the command string into arguments - do not modify
void readCmdTokens(char* cmd, char** cmdTokens) {
  cmd[strlen(cmd) - 1] = '\0'; // drop trailing newline
  int i = 0;
  cmdTokens[i] = strtok(cmd, " "); // tokenize on spaces
  while (cmdTokens[i++] && i < sizeof(cmdTokens)) {
    cmdTokens[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
}

// read one character of input, then discard up to the newline - do not modify
char readChar() {
  char c = getchar();
  while (getchar() != '\n');
  return c;
}

// main method - program entry point
int main() {
  char cmd[81]; // array of chars (a string)
  char* cmdTokens[20]; // array of strings
  int count; // number of times to execute command
  int parallel; // whether to run in parallel or sequentially
  int timeout; // max seconds to run set of commands (parallel) or each command (sequentially)

  while (TRUE) { // main shell input loop

    // begin parsing code - do not modify
    printf("clonsh> ");
    fgets(cmd, sizeof(cmd), stdin);
    if (cmd[0] == '\n') continue;
    readCmdTokens(cmd, cmdTokens);
    do {
      printf("  count> ");
      count = readChar() - '0';
    }
    while (count <= 0 || count > 9);
    printf("  [p]arallel or [s]equential> ");
    parallel = (readChar() == 'p') ? TRUE : FALSE;
    do {
      printf("  timeout> ");
      timeout = readChar() - '0';
    }while (timeout < 0 || timeout > 9);
    // end parsing code


    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                    //
    // TODO: use cmdTokens, count, parallel, and timeout  //
    // to implement the rest of closh                     //
    //                                                    //
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    int pid;
    //clock_t myClock;
    for (int i=0;i<count; i++)
    {

        pid = fork();

        if (pid == 0)
       {
            printf("My process ID : %d\n", getpid());
            //printf("My parent process ID : %d\n", getppid());
            execvp(cmdTokens[0], cmdTokens);

       }

        /*myClock=clock();
        if (myClock>9000000)
            kill (pid, SIGKILL);*/

    }



return 0;

  }


}
```

Comment: While not a specific duplicate, this question asks in more detail what you are trying to accomplish: [Waitpid equivalent with timeout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282176/waitpid-equivalent-with-timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There basically two solutions :

1. each forked process kills himself after some delay. This is easy to do with the help of `alarm(sec)`. Such a call will let the system sends a `SIGALRM` signal to the calling process after a specified delay.
2. the parent process controls the lifetime of its children. The main problem is to avoid busy waiting. The second problem is the difficulty to manage different timers. A basic solution is to have a table of children associated with a delay. Then you can use `alarm()` to catch and timeout event an `kill()` the processes, and then sets a new `alarm()` for the sequel... After a call to alarm the parent process can quietly go sleeping with a call to `wait()`. If such a call terminates successfully, you just have to remove the processes from the table.

Comment: Thank you ! This pushed me in the general right direction