# Trying to wake parent process up with Alarm() if timeout is reached

Tags: c, process

I'm writing a process related program in C and I'm having a small problem waking up a process:

I have a parent process that I put to sleep with waitpid(), but I need it to carry on either when its children complete, or when a certain time is reached. My plan was to call alarm(timeout), and then call waitpid(-1,&status,0), so essentially the process would wait until a child finished, and if the child didnt finish within the timeout time, a signal would be sent and the parent would exit after killing the child. The issue I'm having is that this alarm() call just prints "Alarm clock" to the console, and it doesnt seem to be waking up the parent in time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a signal handler for SIGALRM. alarm() sends a SIGALRM signal when it expires, and if you don't handle that signal it will terminate your process.

```
static int g_timeout;
void alrm_handler(int signo)
{
    g_timeout = 1;
}
```

And in your main code, e.g.:

```
signal(SIGALRM, alrm_handler);
alarm(10);
pid_t p = waitpid(-1,&status,0);
if (p == -1) {
    if (errno == EINTR && g_timeout) {
        //timeout occured
     } else {
       //other error 
     }
 }
```

Comment: when timeout occurs, g_timeout is being set to 0 (which, since g_timeout is in the file global scope, is actually its' initial value,  Then the line: 'if (errno == EINTR && g_timeout) {' is always going to go to the else condition because (irregardless of a timeout event) the g_timeout will be 0

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of this question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282176/waitpid-equivalent-with-timeout>

Comment: @user3629249 yes, it was a typo, I've corrected it.