# Killing child process after timeout, with multiple children?

Tags: c

I've used this code sample to automatically kill a child process after the timeout period, however it doesn't work when there is multiple child processes (this code is running in a thread pool). After one child process is terminated the following ones aren't terminated after the timeout period and continue until they exit normally. so I would imagine the wires are being crossed somewhere. I arrived at this conclusion from answers to this question: [Waitpid equivalent with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282176/waitpid-equivalent-with-timeout). Full code sample:
https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/code-examples/signal-waiting-sigtimedwait

```c
/* The program creates a child process and waits for it to finish. If a timeout
 * elapses the child is killed. Waiting is done using sigtimedwait(). Race
 * condition is avoided by blocking the SIGCHLD signal before fork().
 */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

static pid_t fork_child (void)
{
    int p = fork ();

    if (p == -1) {
        perror ("fork");
        exit (1);
    }

    if (p == 0) {
        puts ("child: sleeping...");
        sleep (10);
        puts ("child: exiting");
        exit (0);
    }

    return p;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sigset_t mask;
    sigset_t orig_mask;
    struct timespec timeout;
    pid_t pid;

    sigemptyset (&mask);
    sigaddset (&mask, SIGCHLD);

    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, &orig_mask) < 0) {
        perror ("sigprocmask");
        return 1;
    }

    pid = fork_child ();

    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_nsec = 0;

    do {
        if (sigtimedwait(&mask, NULL, &timeout) < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                /* Interrupted by a signal other than SIGCHLD. */
                continue;
            }
            else if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                printf ("Timeout, killing child\n");
                kill (pid, SIGKILL);
            }
            else {
                perror ("sigtimedwait");
                return 1;
            }
        }

        break;
    } while (1);

    if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        perror ("waitpid");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem better than "doesn't work". What is the exact expected behaviour and actual behaviour? For example, the problem you describe is for multiple child processes yet the code shown never creates more than one child.

Comment: "this code is run in a threadpool". You need to show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Who's to say there is not a problem with the threading code? So we need to see **exact** code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have multiple threads trying to wait for children at the same time using that approach, then I'm not surprised that you encounter problems.  You cannot then assume that a particular child's `SIGCHLD` will be handled by the thread that is trying to wait for that child.

Comment: @JohnBollinger What would be a better way to approach waiting for child processes in multiple threads?

Comment: ... with child running time limit enforcement?  It's tricky.  You'll definitely need shared data tracking which thread is waiting on which child, and how long it is willing to wait before killing the child.  Then I'd look into having a separate thread dedicated to handling the child process management duties on behalf of all the others.  That's going to be complicated, but I think not as much so as trying to do without a dedicated thread for that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger unfortunately I am restricted to completely managing the process inside the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to recommend polling with `waitpid()`, using the `WNOHANG`flag to prevent that from blocking, but I think I came up with something better: a pipe from the child, and `select()` in the parent.

Specifically,

1. the parent creates a pipe before forking.
2. after (successfully) forking, the parent closes its copy of the write end of the pipe.
3. the parent then uses `select()`, with the wanted timeout, to wait for the pipe to become available for reading.  The child does not need actually to write to the pipe, or even to know about it.  The write end will be closed when the child terminates, and that will make the read end available for reading (the EOF signal).
4. If the timeout expires then the parent sends a `SIGTERM` to the child.
5. Either way, the parent collects the child with `waitpid()`.

Be sure to check the status code provided by `waitpid` if you care whether the child terminated normally, because there is a chance that it terminates normally between the timeout expiring and the `SIGTERM` being delivered, in which case I think `waitpid` will (properly) show it as having terminated normally.  Of course, it can also terminate on account of receiving a signal from another source or for another reason -- a `SIGSEGV`, for example.

Here are the bones of such an approach. You'll need to add details to make it work for you, and error-handling to make it robust:

```
pid_t child_pid;
int term_pipe[2];

pipe(term_pipe);
child_pid = fork();

switch (child_pid) {
    case -1:
        // handle error
        break;
    case 0:
        // child
        // ... whatever ...
        exit(0);
}
close(term_pipe[1]);  // essential

fd_set read_fds;
struct timeval timeout = { /* timeout */ };
int result;

FD_ZERO(read_fds);
FD_SET(term_pipe[0], read_fds);
result = select(term_pipe[0] + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

if (result == 0) {
    // timeout
    kill(child_pid, SIGTERM);
} else if (result < 0) {
    // handle error
    // in particular, you may need to resume waiting if the error is EINTR
} else {
    // the child terminated within the timeout
    assert(result == 1);
}

// don't forget to close the read end of the pipe
close(term_pipe[0]);

int status;
pid_t collected_pid = waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0);

if (collected_pid < 0) {
    // handle error
} else {
    assert(collected_pid == child_pid);
    // ... test the status to see how the child terminated ...
    // ...
}
```

Note that you want normal handling of child termination with this, so do not block `SIGCHLD` as your code presently does.

Comment: Ah, strange.  I would have thought that you could at least vote on answers to your own question.