# sigtimedwait "suddenly" fails with EINTR - does not report the signal even with sigfillset(&mask)

Tags: c, linux

I am using basically this code from the question [Waitpid equivalent with timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20173592) [here](https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/slash/-/blob/0431fada33e6e35898ff6f8aa2982f751c11d480/src/fellow_log_test.c#L706-724):

```c
sigaddset(&mask, SIGCHLD);
i = sigtimedwait(&mask, NULL, &timeo);
if (i < 0) {
    assert(errno == EAGAIN);
    i = kill(pid, SIGABRT);
    assert(i == 0 || i == ESRCH);
}
(void) waitpid(pid, &i, 0);
```

The idea is to terminate a child process after a timeout if it does not itself terminate before the timeout.

The code worked for ~two years on my machine without issues, and now, seemingly out of the blue, it started to fail with `` fellow_log_test.c:720: forkrun: Assertion `errno == EAGAIN' failed. ``. In gdb:

```
(gdb) fr 6
#6  0x000055b2d8b8fa92 in forkrun (tc=0x55b2d8bd2aa0 <tc_adddel_netzero>, killafter=0.71720549847983861, t_priv=0x0)
    at fellow_log_test.c:720
720         assert(errno == EAGAIN);
(gdb) p errno
$1 = 4
(gdb) p i
$2 = -1
```

```bash
$ errno 4
EINTR 4 Interrupted system call
```

system: Debian 12.2 / kernel: `6.1.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.38-2 (2023-07-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I am aware of the usual `do ... while (errno == EINTR)` pattern, but I would like to understand how this spurious wakeup comes about.

According to the documentation, there should be another signal delivered, so I filled the signal mask with `sigfillset(&mask);` and also added a `siginfo_t`, but there is no information on the wakeup:

```c
sigfillset(&mask);
siginfo_t info = {0};
i = sigtimedwait(&mask, &info, &timeo);
```

gdb:

```
(gdb) p i
$2 = -1
(gdb) p info
$3 = {si_signo = 0, si_errno = 0, si_code = 0, __pad0 = 0, _sifields = {_pad = {0 <repeats 28 times>}, _kill = {
      si_pid = 0, si_uid = 0}, _timer = {si_tid = 0, si_overrun = 0, si_sigval = {sival_int = 0, sival_ptr = 0x0}}, 
    _rt = {si_pid = 0, si_uid = 0, si_sigval = {sival_int = 0, sival_ptr = 0x0}}, _sigchld = {si_pid = 0, 
      si_uid = 0, si_status = 0, si_utime = 0, si_stime = 0}, _sigfault = {si_addr = 0x0, si_addr_lsb = 0, 
      _bounds = {_addr_bnd = {_lower = 0x0, _upper = 0x0}, _pkey = 0}}, _sigpoll = {si_band = 0, si_fd = 0}, 
    _sigsys = {_call_addr = 0x0, _syscall = 0, _arch = 0}}}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: Also asked on Mastodon https://fosstodon.org/@slink/111301491021428933

Comment: issue: https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/slash/-/issues/31

Comment: Who is teaching you to use `assert()` for error checking?  `assert()` is **horrible** for error checking - it summarily kills the entire process if the assertion fails. That is a completely unsuitable overreaction for most run-time errors.  Like when a call fails because it was interrupted and needs merely to be restarted. And if the code is compiled `NDEBUG` defined (as many toolchains do with "release" builds,,,) `assert()` is reduced to a no-op and all your error checking disappears.

Comment: The man page for every system call documents the errors it can return, and under what conditions.  `sigtimedwait(2)` says for `EINTR`: "The  wait  was interrupted by a signal handler; see signal(7).  (This handler
              was for a signal other than one of those in set.)"  So, does your program install handlers for other signals?

Comment: The `siginfo_t` is only filled in when the interrupting signal is one of the ones in your set (in which case `sigtimedwait` returns success).  So it's normal that you don't see any information there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle put aside that this code is only used to run tests, in the varnish-cache project we deliberately use asserts in production code and lots of them. The basic idea is exactly what you are hinting at: We want to catch exactly the right runtime errors, no more, no less. Thus, we try to always trigger an assert for anything unexpected. Killing the process is, in my mind, a much better option than having lots (untested) exception handling code paths which may contain security issues, lead to unforeseen state etc. etc. I believe this strategy made Varnish-Cache super reliable and safe.

Comment: @NateEldredge I am setting `SIGPIPE` and `SIGHUP` to `SIG_IGN`, but removing the respective `sigaction()` calls did not change anything. I understand that a `siginfo_t` argument would only contain information for signals on the mask, I only printed it in gdb for completeness. My main question is really: Why would `sigtimedwait()` return failure with `EINTR` for a mask initialized with `sigfillset()`? This does not match my understanding of the documentation which you also quoted.

Comment: You might be interested in an alternative approach using the newish [`pidfd_open()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_open.2.html) syscall combined with `poll()` etc. with a timeout.

Comment: @Shawn thank you for the pointer, the code is supposed to be portable

Comment: @NilsGoroll *Thus, we try to always trigger an assert for anything unexpected.* And thus your program **dies** because of a feature that's [clearly documented](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/sigtimedwait.html): "The `sigtimedwait()` and `sigwaitinfo()` functions may fail if:

[EINTR]
    The wait was interrupted by an unblocked, caught signal. It shall be documented in system documentation whether this error causes these functions to fail."  Thus your use of `assert()` made your code non-portable and unreliable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: But OP claims that no signals are being caught.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I want my code to be _correct_. If it is, `sigtimedwait()` should return either because of a timeout or because `SIGCHLD` was received. Anything else I consider a bug in my program or elsewhere.

When I use a fully set mask to `sigtimedwait()`, it reports no signal either. So if all else is correct and we understand the documentation, what _is_ the "unblocked, caught signal"? As long as I have such an unanswered question, I need to assume that my code is _wrong_ and I _want_ my program to **die**. As early as possible. So I can fix the bug and avoid things go haywire.

Comment: This is not conclusive yet, but it looks like scheduling the timeout fails: https://gitlab.com/uplex/varnish/slash/-/issues/31#note_1622111897

Comment: Are you able to make a [mcve] of this behavior?  Or, can you reproduce it when running your program under `strace -vvv`?  This would show you if a signal is in fact being delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comments and the linked commits, it seems that the issue was that the code had not previously blocked `SIGCHLD`.

The normal way to use `sigtimedwait` and friends is to block the relevant signals *before* they could possibly be generated.  In the case of `SIGCHLD`, that would normally mean to block it before you fork off any child processes.  Otherwise, you have a race where the signal could be delivered before your call to `sigtimedwait`, and so the `sigtimedwait` would be too late to accept it.

If you have it unblocked, then in addition to introducing a race bug, you run into a corner case that doesn't seem to be well described in either the Linux man page nor in the POSIX spec.  When a signal is pending, it is supposed to either:

1. be *delivered* (executing the signal handler or the "default disposition" for the signal, e.g. killing the process), if not currently blocked; or
2. be *accepted* by a `sigtimedwait` or similar that is currently in progress; or
3. remain pending until one of the previous two options becomes possible (i.e. deliver the signal when it is unblocked, or let it be accepted if a call to `sigtimedwait` is made later).

In this case both #1 and #2 are possible, and it is unclear from the docs which one is supposed to win.  It appears that what happened here is that #1 won: the signal was delivered instead of being accepted by `sigtimedwait`, and as such, `sigtimedwait` returned with `EINTR` as it normally does when a signal is delivered.

The Linux man page, in documenting the `EINTR` return, does say "(This handler was for a signal other than one of those in `set`)", but they are probably thinking of the normal case where the signals in `set` were all blocked.

Anyway, the fix is, as you noted, to block the signal beforehand.